# Is there a way to get the Perl interpreter to list all the global variables in a .pl file?

Tags: perl, global-variables

I have a huge system that I'm converting from a cgi to a daemon, and I need to find all the variables that end up being global (as in not declared with `my $`...).
They are probably intended to be scoped locally, but in Perl if you accidentally forget, it doesn't care, but now I do.

I gotta figure the perl interpreter can tell the difference, so is there a way to get it to tell me? I could go through all the code by hand, looking for declarations, but there are thousands and thousands and thousands of lines of code in this system.

Comment: Just use `use strict;`. And don't forget `use warnings;`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[perldoc strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) will show all variables not declared with `my`:

```
$ perl -Mstrict=vars -c -e '$x=5; my $y=7; $z=6;'
Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Global symbol "$z" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
-e had compilation errors.
```

The same thing with a list of files:

```
$ perl -Mstrict=vars -c *.pl
```

See also [strictv -- how unstrict is your code?](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1052586); this will give you a short summary of the variables.

Here is another way using [perldoc B::Xref](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Xref.html)

```
$ perl -MO=Xref -e '$x=5; my $y=7; $z=6;'

... lots of verbose output

  Subroutine (main)
    Package (lexical)
      $y                i1
    Package main
      $x                1
      $z                1
```

Comment: Interesting application of strict. :)

Comment: @briand d foy, Actually, no. The OP wants to make sure he didn't forget to `my`, and that's *exactly* why everyone uses strict.

Comment: He wants to eliminate "Global variables" and i think he mean "package Variables". But with "use strict" you don't see them. If you declare "our $foo" then "use strict" doesn't complain about anything and you still use "Package Variables".

Answer (score 0):

With the PadWalker Module you can see all variables in a specific scope. You can see variables declared with "my" and "our".

You should still use "use strict" but using "use strict" does not show you global variables that you declare as global.

For example this example still has a global variable and strict does not do anything

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
our $foo;
```

With PadWalker you can use something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DDP;
use PadWalker qw(peek_our);

our $var;

print p peek_our(0);
```

The output is

```
\ {
    $var   \ undef
}
```

Sure, you only should use PadWalker for Debugging.